# Add conditional css style sheet to xpage

Tags: css, xpages

Is it possible to add a conditional style sheet to an xpage.

Done like this in html:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="../../blueprint/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->
```

Though about adding with computed field set to HTML and code javascript like:

```
return '<!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"../../blueprint/ie.css\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"screen, projection\"><![endif]-->'
```

but then it would be included in the body of page, not the header with the other style sheets.

Need for a proof of concept putting together using http://blueprintcss.org.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

an Xpage theme would be great for this. There is an example included with the notes install.

go to C:\ **Notes directory** \xsp\nsf\themes

make a copy of webStandard.theme, rename is webStandard.**xml** and open in an editor of your choice, this will show you a lot of examples of what a theme can do. Apply attributes, add resources, compute these via expressions etc.

Snippet:

```
    <resource rendered="#{javascript:context.isDirectionRTL()}">
        <content-type>text/css</content-type>
        <href>/.ibmxspres/global/theme/webstandard/xspRTL.css</href>
    </resource>

    <!-- IE Specific -->
    <resource rendered="#{javascript:context.getUserAgent().isIE(0,6)}">
        <content-type>text/css</content-type>
        <href>/.ibmxspres/global/theme/webstandard/xspIE06.css</href>
    </resource>
    <resource rendered="#{javascript:context.getUserAgent().isIE(7,8)}">
        <content-type>text/css</content-type>
        <href>/.ibmxspres/global/theme/webstandard/xspIE78.css</href>
    </resource>
```

Comment: That's probabbly the best way to do it. See also here (http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_themes) for some guidelines on how to use themes.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the *rendered* property with SSJS to show an element for IE only:

*rendered="#{javascript:context.getUserAgent().isIE()}"*

Then your CSS ressource will only added to the generated HTML response if a XPage is opened with Internet Explorer.

**EDIT:**
In your case this should fit your requirements:

```
<xp:this.resources>
   <xp:styleSheet href="../../blueprint/ie.css"
      rendered="#{javascript:context.getUserAgent().isIE(0,7)}"
      media="screen, projection">
   </xp:styleSheet>
</xp:this.resources>
```

Comment: Cool!  That did the trick with the proof of concept.  Thanks!